# Can I connect to the monitor only using display port cable and the other 2 (VGA and HDMI) may remain unconnected?

Tags: display, hdmi, connection, vga, displayport

There is a 165 Hz 1920x1080 monitor I want to buy has VGA (D-Sub), DP 1.2 and HDMI 1.4 ports.

1. How do I connect it to make things appear on the screen?  Can I connect to the monitor only using display port cable and the other 2 (VGA and HDMI) may remain unconnected?
2. And if yes then will I be able to experience the full hd 165 Hz?

Comment: Please edit your question: What are you going to connect to the monitor? What is the exact model of display you are planning on buying? In general, only one port — DP or VGA or HDMI — are used to connect. The other ports are there as a convenience.

Comment: One normal only used one port to connect to a single device since the display can only display one mode at a time. Your question about of using one port will work is confusing to say the least.

Comment: Why asking when you can just try and see what happens? What risk does this create?